# After submitting, wait until ajax finishes and hide form

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal-7

I use a simple form that returns results using ajax (drupal 7 views). I need the form to hide after it returns results - after hitting submit button, wait until ajax finishes. Is it possible to do something like this? It is not working for me. Thank you.

```
(function ($) { 
    $('#edit-submit-betterexposed').click(function() {
        $( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
            $('#views-exposed-form-betterexposed-page-1').hide();
        }); 
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: can you bind the ajax call `.promise`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach (not tetsted): enable ajax in views settings, and in js file do something like this:

```
(function ($) { 
    $('#SOME_ELEMENT_IN_EXPOSED_FORM').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('form').submit(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```